# Can the heat given to a thermodynamic system decrease the temperature of the system,I.e. specific heat capacity can be negative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I am confused as it is written that sometimes it is true to say that heat given to a body can decrease its temperature.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232990/are-there-any-known-negative-heat-capacities (another example of a negative heat capacity is black holes)

Comment: Is it saying that it is true or asking if it is possible? I don’t read it as a statement. Are you quoting this exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that heat capacity and specific heat can never be negative. Now, if the question was is it possible for a system to undergo a process in which heat is added and its temperature decreases, my answer would be yes. For this to happen, the work done by a closed system would need to exceed the heat added to the system so that it's internal energy decreases according to the first law

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

and if a change in internal energy results in a temperature decrease. That would be the case if the system was an ideal gas, because for an ideal gas, any process

$$\Delta U=C_{v}\Delta T$$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd be interested in the reason for the down vote. I don't mind a down vote if I can learn something from it.